# Driveline Bottom Bracket

Tags: drivetrain

I am thinking of replacing my Shimano Deore Bottom Bracket SM BB52 with a Driveline X Type instead.I want to know whether it is compatible to do so before I proceed.
Thanks,
Louis.

Answer (score 1):

Googling for 'Driveline X Type bottom bracket' produces no useful results so it's impossible to provide direct guidance

Shimano Hollowtech II external MTB bottom brackets such SM BB52 as the are often described as "BB92" type, that is 24mm axle, ~92mm total width. (There are also Shimano press fit BBs that have these dimensions, and Shimano MTB cranks fit in either).

So, you need a Driveline BB that says it's compatible with BB92.